# Linking MySQL Connector Jar To My Dependencies Java Play Framework 1.x

Tags: java, mysql-connector, playframework-1.x

Using the following connection string credentials in my application.conf file:

```
   db.default.url=mysql://localhost:3306/test
   db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   db.default.user=user
   db.default.pass=password
```

I get the following error in the console:

```
A database error occured : Cannot connected to the database[default], No suitable driver found for mysql://localhost:3306/test
```

So then in my project/lib directory, I have placed the following jar:

```
mysql-connector-java-5.1.48
```

What is the proper syntax then, to include in my dependency file? This is how it looks now:

```
require:
    - play
```

How do I tell this file it needs what's in project/lib?

Answer (score 0):

When you add a JAR file to your project's lib folder, Play FW adds it to classpath by default. You don't need to tell the framework that the file is there.